# Copy from remote computer to local computer SSH (Ubuntu Server 10.04)

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-10.04, scp

`scp filename user@ip_address:/location` will copy a file from my local computer to a remote computer... However I need to copy a file from the remote computer back to the local computer.

Is there any way to specify to pull a certain file down from a remote computer via ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the oposite way, like any copy/move command.

```
scp user@ip_address:/location/to/file /location
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#How_it_works: